# Viewing info and debug logs from the Console application

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, logging

I have a Swift 3 Cocoa application that uses Apple's Unified Logging, like this:

```
import os    
class MyClass
{
    @available(OSX 10.12, *)
    static let scribe = OSLog(subsystem: "com.mycompany.myapp", category: "myapp")

    func SomeFunction(){

        if #available(OSX 10.12, *){
            os_log("Test Error Message", log: MyClass.scribe, type: .error)
        }

        if #available(OSX 10.12, *){
            os_log("Test Info Message", log: MyClass.scribe, type: .info)
        }

        if #available(OSX 10.12, *){
            os_log("Test Debug Message", log: MyClass.scribe, type: .debug)
        }
    } 
}
```

Within the Console application, both `Include Info Messages` and `Include Debug Messages` are turned on.

[image]

When `os_log` is called, only the `error` type message is visible in the Console application. Using terminal, with this command, all message types are visible in the Terminal output:

```
`sudo log stream --level debug`
```

I've tried running the Console app as root, via sudo from the command line and the same issue occurs; no debug or info messages can be seen, even though they're set to being turned on under the Action menu.

Setting system-wide logging to be debug, has no effect on the Console application output:

```
sudo log config --mode level:debug
```

What am I missing and how can I view debug and info messages in the Console application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple responded on their Developer forums and confirmed that they have repeated this issue on 10.12.5, so it is is a bug in the OS.

A bug report was filled for the upcoming 10.13 Developer Preview and has been fixed in 10.13 version3 (17A306f)